# Console application no more console after ILMerged

Tags: c#, ilmerge

I am using ***ILMerge*** to merge the used libraries for a console application. After its merged, the resulting exe just finishes execution in a second and runs in the background(does not show its output for `Console.WriteLine`).
What Can i do to actually run it as a console application ?

Comment: Try running ILMerge with the command line option `/target:exe`

Comment: @mikez write as answer so that I can mark it as answer

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down. It was useful to me. (+1)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Run ILMerge with the command line option `/target:exe`